# Google Analytic on a php site?

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have some problem to get the Google Analytics to work. I have got a analyticsTracking.php file and this is included on my index.php page like this :

```
<?php
include("begin.php");
include($subroot . "templateconfig.php");
include($cms['tngpath'] . "genlib.php");
include($cms['tngpath'] . "getlang.php");
include($cms['tngpath'] . "$mylanguage/text.php");
tng_db_connect($database_host,$database_name,$database_username,$database_password) or exit;
include($cms['tngpath'] . "checklogin.php");

//Insert the following lines in your index.php to take advantage of template switching
if($templateswitching && $templatenum) {
include($cms['tngpath'] . "templates/template$templatenum/index.php");
exit;
}
//end of lines to be inserted for template switching

$flags['noicons'] = true;
$flags['noheader'] = true;
tng_header( $text['mnuheader'], $flags );
?>

<!-- "Home Page" (the text for these messages can be found at near the bottom of text.php -->
<h1><?php echo $text['mnuheader']; ?></h1>



<p><strong>Please customize this page!</strong></p> 

<?php include ("analyticsTracking.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

When looking on the genereted index.html there is no data from the analyticsTracking.php at all? Why?

Pleas note, I am not working with PHP so all this is new to me.

**Edit1:** Sorry, I am using index.php and not index.html.

**Edit2:** analyticsTracking.php contains somthing like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = ((" https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
try{
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxxx-x");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}
</script> <?php
// End Analytics tracking code
?>
```

Comment: What does `analyticsTracking.php` contain?

Comment: Generated `index.html`? You're working with PHP, but aren't using it. How do you expect the Google Analytics script to function if it isn't being loaded in your pages?

Comment: @Blender > Sorry, Im using the index.php.

Comment: It all looks good to me (except the space between `include` and `(`) - although that's just my personal preference. What do you get when you turn on errors? `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the problem was that I used the wrong php file. It is working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

So if I'm understanding correctly, your index.php script includes analyticsTracking.php, yet when you view index.php in a browser, you don't see any of the HTML from analyticsTracking.php.

```
<?php include ("analyticsTracking.php"); ?>
```

Is that the correct path? Is analyticsTracking.php in the same directory as index.php? Try changing the include to a require and see if it prints an error when the webpage is refreshed.